# TextView setSelected(false) Does Not Stop Marquee

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, textview

I have a `TextView` that I am using in a `CardFragment`, within a `GridViewPager`. The `TextView` is set to marquee forever. But when the `TextView` is not actually in view by the user, I want it to stop scrolling.

```
<TextView
    android:id"@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

For the `TextView` to actually start scrolling I call `setSelected(true)`, but when I call `setSelected(false)` in the fragment's `onPause()` method, nothing happens, the text continues to scroll. I know that the `onPause()` is getting called, and when I call `isSelected()` on the `TextView` it does return false.

The text only stops scrolling when I get more than two pages away. I believe this is because the fragment is actually getting destroyed when it is not close to the current page, then recreated when it comes back into play.

How can I get the `TextView` to stop scrolling (without actually destroying the fragment)? I have also tried `setMarqueeRepeatLimit(0)` (along with `setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1)` when it is selected again), but that does not work either.

**EDIT:** Current xml code:

```
<TextView
    android:id"@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Fragment code:

```
public class MyCardFragment extends CardFragment {
    private static final String TAG = MyCardFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mText;

    private Context mContext;

    private TextView mTextView;

    public static MyCardFragment create(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    @OVerride
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateContentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_fragment, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTextView.setText(mText);
        mTextView.setSelected(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        Log.d(TAG, "text: " + mTextView.getText() + " ellipsize: " + mTextView.getEllipsize());
    }

    public void onSelected() {
        mTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        Log.d(TAG, "text: " + mTextView.getText() + " ellipsize: " + mTextView.getEllipsize());
    }
}
```

And my activity implements `GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to call `onSelected()`:

```
public class MainActivity implements GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int row, int column) {
        MyCardFragment fragment = (MyCardFragment) mPagerAdapter.findExistingFragment(row, column);
        fragment.onSelected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setEllipsize() to set the ellipsize property to none.

Below code works for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private TextUtils.TruncateAt noneEllipsize;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        noneEllipsize = textView.getEllipsize(); // activity_main.xml has ellipsize property set to 'none'.
        textView.setSelected(true);
    }

    public void btnToggleMarqueeClick(View view) {
        if ( textView.getEllipsize() != noneEllipsize ) {
            textView.setEllipsize(noneEllipsize);
        } else {
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/btnToggleMarquee"
    android:onClick="btnToggleMarqueeClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Suggesting following changes to your code

Update layout xml as follows

```
<TextView
android:id"@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Update fragment code as follows:

```
public class MyCardFragment extends CardFragment {
    private static final String TAG = MyCardFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mText;

    private Context mContext;

    private TextView mTextView;

    private TextUtils.TruncateAt noneEllipsize;

    public static MyCardFragment create(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    @OVerride
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateContentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_fragment, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        noneEllipsize = mTextView.getEllipsize();
        mTextView.setText(mText);
        mTextView.setSelected(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mTextView.setEllipsize(noneEllipsize);
        Log.d(TAG, "text: " + mTextView.getText() + " ellipsize: " + mTextView.getEllipsize());
    }

    public void onSelected() {
        mTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        Log.d(TAG, "text: " + mTextView.getText() + " ellipsize: " + mTextView.getEllipsize());
    }
}
```

The onPageSelected() method in MainActivity remains as it is.

Comment: Still not working, the text just keeps scrolling even though I log `mTextView.getEllipize()` and it prints `NONE`. I tried setting it to `TextUtil.TruncateAt.END` as well, but no luck.

Comment: I just added the current code in an edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer to suggest edits to your code. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setEllipsize(null)
```

From the doc:

> Causes words in the text that are longer than the view is wide to be
>   ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You may also want to
>   setSingleLine() or setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean) to constrain the
>   text to a single line. **Use `null` to turn off ellipsizing**. If
>   setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, only END and
>   MARQUEE are supported (other ellipsizing types will not do anything).